# Detect dynamic javascript for xssi

Tags: javascript, xss, cross-site

I am trying to understand the cross site script inclusion. i have read the paper of sebastian lekeis ([click here for paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=36&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjeqfONwb7WAhULvI8KHf8aAew4HhAWCEQwBQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kittenpics.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F05%2Fscript-leakage.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHaaDEb5uGuGEU3cfCVqJEnTAIhxw) and [slide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj598LNwb7WAhXIu48KHSSSDmMQFgg3MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.owasp.org%2Fimages%2Ff%2Ff3%2FYour_Script_in_My_Page_What_Could_Possibly_Go_Wrong_-_Sebastian_Lekies%252BBen_Stock.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHKZfN3z6hlnfjldrB0KczleYV7NA) and [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mnkgg3q51Ps)) and got some idea about it. Here detecting dynamic javascript is a part of the methodology and I have some confusion here.

What exactly it means by dynamic javascript detection. Here it is told that the same script file would be requested twice. one with authentication and another without. but my confusion is if I request suppose `script.js` file twice how can it will differ. The server will always send the file with the same line of codes. isn't it..??

After getting the script file the browser will execute the file and when it is finished then it may differ from one to another.

suppose,

```
$http.get("home/GetInfo", function(response){
  $scope.userName = response;
});
```

here `$scope.userName` value may differ but the script file will remain same.

What's wrong in my understanding..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic JavaScript would be where the script file is processed by the server to insert values based on cookies etc, before it's sent to the client. This is sometimes used to pass some initial data to the client.

So the script file contents might be like:

```
sessionId = "<%= getSessionId() %>";

$http.get("home/GetInfo?sessionId="+sessionId, function(response){
  $scope.userName = response;
});
```

and when requesting it, you get something like:

```
sessionId = "d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249";

$http.get("home/GetInfo?sessionId="+sessionId, function(response){
  $scope.userName = response;
});
```

The sessionId literal would be different each time the script's requested, which when detected shows that dynamic JavaScript was used.

Comment: but this is not .js file. It may .jsp or .cshtml or something like that. thus it is not js file, how can i request the script file twice as the paper said (with and without authentication) ??

Comment: @SadidKhan They found js files that were generated differently based on cookie values. First they logged in to the site and kept track of the contents of every js file. Then they requested the same files again without cookies enabled. They used a custom extension, but you can get the same result by manually logging in and out of the site between requests.